# What is main differences between FieldCloning and PropertyCloning?

Tags: c#, cloning

I use Nuclex as cloning framework. But i cannot differ DeepFieldClone vs PropertyFieldClone.

Comment: First clones everything (all fields and properties with backing fields). Second clones only properties.